# scala - return different value for comprehension for matching patterns

Tags: scala

I'm matching and replacing 3 patterns in a for comprehension. The patterns are ordered and I expect the
for comprehension to yield ans1 or ans2 or ans3 if a replacement occurs and continue the iteration.
I don't want to execute ans2 and ans3 if replacement happens for ans1

```
val pat1 ="""(?sm)^\s*#.+?$""".r
val pat2 ="""(?sm)^(.+?((['"])[^\\3]*\3))(.*)""".r
val pat3 ="""(?sm)(#.+?$)""".r
val ansx = for { str <- file_list

     str2 = str.toString
     ans1 = pat1.replaceAllIn(str2, "") // if replacement happens yield ans1
     ans2 = pat2.replaceAllIn(ans1, m => {
         "".concat(m.group(1))
       })  // if replacement happens yield ans2 
     ans3 = pat3.replaceAllIn(ans2, "") 
} yield ans3
```

To do that when I wrap the ans2 with if() condition, I'm getting error.

```
if( ans1 == str2 ) {
                ans2 =   pat2.replaceAllIn(ans1, m => {
                     "".concat(m.group(1))
                   })
                 }
```

it says cannot resolve symbol ans2.
Is there a simple way to solve this?.

Adding sample data for file_list, actually it comes from a file.

```
# comment1
# comment2
#hbase_table_name=mytable # hbase table.
hbase_table_name=newtable # hbase table.
hbase_txn_family=txn
app_name= "cust#100"  # Name of the application
#app_name= "cust#100"  # Name of the application
app_user= 'all#50,all2#100'  # users
hbase.zookeeper.quorum=localhost
zookeeper.znode.parent=/hbase-secure
hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort=2181
# from comments, other lines
hbase_table_name=newtable ## hbase table.
app_user= 'all#50,all2#100'  # users - "all" of them
```

Comment: @jwvh.. added test data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want, but it's a little hard to say without test data.

```
val pat1 ="""(?sm)^\s*#.+?$""".r
val pat2 ="""(?sm)^(.+?((['"])[^\\3]*\3)).*""".r
val pat3 ="""(?sm)#.+?$""".r.unanchored

val rslt = file_list.map{
  case s @ pat1()      => pat1.replaceAllIn(s, "")
  case s @ pat2(a,_,_) => pat2.replaceAllIn(s, a)
  case s @ pat3()      => pat3.replaceAllIn(s, "")
  case s => s
}
```

Comment: yes.. it works..btw why for comprehension doesn't work?

Comment: Your `for` comprehension has one generator, `<-`, followed by four simple assignments, `a = b`. Whether `replaceAllIn()` makes 100 substitutions, or none at all, it still returns a result `String` used to complete the assignment, which is a good thing. If an assignment should fail it would terminate the entire `for` block. A `for` comprehension will stop on first failure. A pattern match will stop after fist success, i.e. first match.

Answer (score 1):

```
object YieldPatterns {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val pat1 ="""(?sm)^\s*#.+?$"""
    val pat2 ="""(?sm)^(.+?((['"])[^\\3]*\3))(.*)"""
    val pat3 ="""(?sm)(#.+?$)"""
    val file_list = List("aaaa","1111","222")

    val output : List[String] = file_list.map(fileName => {
      var ans = fileName
      if(ans.matches(pat1)) {
        ans = pat1.r.replaceAllIn(ans,"")
      }
      if(ans.matches(pat2)) {
        ans = pat2.r.replaceAllIn(ans,m => {
          "".concat(m.group(1))
        })
      }
      if(ans.matches(pat3)) {
        ans = pat3.r.replaceAllIn(ans,"")
      }
      ans
    })
    println(output)
  }

}
```

Comment: yes.. this works.. I think for comprehension is not suited for this type of processing.